# How to restore all autovacuum settings to their postgres default

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I made many changes to postgres autovacuum settings such as changing the cost_delay and naptime settings.  I'm not confident what all my changes were---and would like to reset autovacuum settings to their default.

Is there a command I can execute to restore them to their defaults?

Comment: `reset autovacuum` produces `[55P02] ERROR: parameter "autovacuum" cannot be changed now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reset every setting you changed. If you can't remember which settings you changed, you can query [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html) for all non-default values:

```
select name, 
       setting as current_value,
       reset_val, 
       boot_val as original_default, 
       sourcefile, 
       sourceline
from pg_settings
where source <> 'default'
  and name like '%autovacuum%';
```

`reset_val` is the value the setting would revert to if you run `reset <name>;` - this applies to changes you have done in the current session (using `set <name> = ...;`)

What I called `original_default` is the value of that setting which is applied if the parameter is not specified at all.

The columns `sourcefile` and `sourceline` will help you find *where* you changed those values. If that is e.g. `postgresql.auto.conf` then the setting was changed with `alter system` and should be reset using `alter system`.

If it's a different config file (e.g. `postgresql.conf), you will need to edit the file where it was changed.

Comment: How to revert table level autovacuum settings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641863/how-to-restore-all-autovacuum-settings-to-their-postgres-default